# Angular 6 template doesn't update when variable changes

Tags: javascript, angular, templates, angular6

I have a menu object that will end up displaying a menu on the template. One of the menu objects properties is set by a variable that gets changed during the ngOnInit(). At that point, the template is already created I believe, so the menu never updates.

We want the MemberProfile link to display the user ID and not the 'undefined' that it is initialized with.

Check out the stack blitz link.

It's pretty straight forward I know I'm missing something simple.

When you open the menu, I'm printing out the Link Label and the Link URL.
The second link should be `Admin/MemberProfile/45` and not `Admin/MemberProfile/undefined`

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-yu9hty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to understand how template/html rendering in Angular works.

As in your case, since you are rendering your menu link list from an array, `menu.admin`. Angular will not re-render the `*ngFor` block, until it detects changes in the `menu.admin` array. So, you just need to update that array.

Now, what you can do is something like this,

```
public ngOnInit() {
   this.userId = 45;

   this.menu.admin[this.menu.admin.length - 1].link = '/Admin/MemberProfile/' + this.userId
}
```

For more info please refer to [Angular lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).

Answer (score 1):

When the property `menu` is declared and assigned a value, this expression

```
'/Admin/MemberProfile/' + this.userId
```

is evaluated, using the then-current value of `userId`. When you do

```
this.userId = 45;
```

the value of `menu` isn't computed again.

There are several possible solutions. Put the menu layout in the template, instead of the TS (and use `{{ userId }}` there), use RxJS to update the thing dynamically, or simply imperatively recalculate the value of `menu` when changing `userId` (the most crude solution, and requiring the least amount of writing on my part), shown here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qpnaqz?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Player's choice.

Comment: Great solution, however, due to some other code that I left out of the demo for simplicity reasons, this didn't solve my dilemma although it is a perfect approach. Thank you for this!